# skobbler integration into android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, skmaps

How do you integrate Skobbler with an existing project? I followed the steps given on their website but couldn't integrate it successfully. It gives me an error of 'unable to expand jar file'

Comment: Which step gave you that error? What configurations do you have for your project? If you simply ask "How do you integrate Skobbler with an existing project?" we would have to direct you to that website again.

Comment: Hey, I was able to integrate it into the project by simply importing the module sdktools, thanks for the response though.

Comment: Also, do you know any specific resources or documentation that i can follow to render a map using skobbler? Their demo project is a bit difficult to understand.